# Mapping c++/cli entities to tables (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework, c++-cli

I'm trying to map my classes which are defined in a c++/cli library to database by EF6. Table attributes are added to the c++ classes but EF generates

System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'

as soon as accessing any c++ types, but c# mapped types can be instantiated.

any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: EF doesn't know beans about native C++.

Comment: Are the Entity Types all POCOs, ie `ref class` with properties?  Can you post a simple repro?  Also as a workaround, you might simply define your Entity Types in C# and consume them from managed C++.

Comment: @HansPassant entities are .Net classes (public ref class), not native

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft as mentioned in previous comment, classes are managed classes not native accessible from c# code but EF can not map them. it's lot of work to convert them into c# since some of that are legacy code and used to be serialized in text files

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I can create a simple VS2017 solution , is that what you mentioned?

Comment: Best if you can boil it down to something that can be copied into the body of your question.